# Importing dynamic path in Less mixin

Tags: import, less, media-queries

I'm rewriting my Less css structure to be more scalable. I'm looking for an architecture that loads a templates for each media query for each template.

Preferably, I want to load this in a mixin. The current mixin looks like this (but does not allow specific component loading)
`

```
/**
 * Progressive enhancing overrides (mobile first)
 *
 * Mobile loads "mobile.less"
 * Wide mobile loads "mobile.less" and "widemobile.less"
 * Tablet loads "mobile.less", "widemobile.less" and "tablet.less"
 * etc.
 */
.progressive-enhancement() {
  // Mobile layout
  @media only screen {
    @import (less) "../template/mobile";
  }

  (...)
}
```

So what I'm looking for is something like this (not working):

```
.progressive-enhancement(@component: main) {
  // Mobile layout
  @media only screen {
    @import (less) "../template/@{component}/mobile";
  }

  (...)
}
```

This however, does not work, resulting in an error claiming that @component is undefined.

I think the problem is that Less tries to do the import before the mixing is called, not having the @component defined at that stage.

Is there any way to use @import dynamically with variables provided by the mixin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer below. Though to be honest I'm not quite convinced of the whole idea of breaking individual media styles of each component into separate files. So when you need to adjust *the same* property (e.g. font-size) for *the same* styles of *the same* element (e.g. `.button`), you have to open every "device" file for that component and in each find the corresponding lines to modify? Sounds quite tedious and hard to maintain. For me this looks like the whole thing should be implemented exactly up-side-down.

Comment: It's progressive enhancing, so if the font-size is set in mobile, it will be available on tablet and so on, no need to repeat the statement. The goal is to isolate media query logic from actual styling.

Comment: No, I actually mean when you have to provide different values for the same property (font-size or whatever actual property, it does not matter - it's just for example). I.e. how spreading the whole thing over multiple files can be better then for example something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0fa7ee5993ef882aeb28) (yes, it's more verbose, but in the same time I keep all the coupled stuff in one place).

Comment: And btw., (I almost forgot), `(less)` is redundant when you're importing a Less file. just `@import "foobar";` is enough.

Comment: I'm familiar with the short import, but I tend to be more explicit. Note that the "components" are larger sets (not just buttons but let's say navbars or card view sections). These specific per media query templates can become rather large so I decided to split them up ;)

Comment: 'Note that the "components" are larger sets' - that's what I mean, the bigger component grows the harder it becomes to sync styles for various devices. That's why I'd always prefer to keep the same properies of the same elements as close as possible. But well, never mind, it's your choice (I see I'm already gone too offtopic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's impossible. And, yes, this is because Less have to evaluate language entities in certain "typed" order instead of "top-to-bottom" order (roughly it's imports -> mixins -> variables etc.) because of lazy-evaluation principles (there're some internal workarounds possible to handle certain specific things with an exception to this, but those exceptions will never be anything but kludge).

As for your specific use-case, the easiest workaround at first glance would be to use imports instead of mixins, and let the components to specify their own names:

```
// progressive-enhancement.less:

@media only screen {
    @import "@{component}/mobile";
}

// etc.
```

Then for each component you provide its "root" file:

```
// ../template/button.less:
& {
    @component: button;
    @import (multiple) "progressive-enhancement.less";
}
```

.

```
// ../template/toolbar.less:
& {
    @component: toolbar;
    @import (multiple) "progressive-enhancement.less";
}
```

etc.

And finally in your master file you just import those ordinarily:

```
// main.less:
@import "../template/button";
@import "../template/toolbar";
```

(Obviously file names and and their actual locations to be adjusted to your taste).

Comment: Thanks, no is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question so i can use some formatting to show my workaround.

I have this directory structure:

```
less/
- components/
  - navbar/
    - mobile.less
    - tablet.less
  (...)
- config/
  - defaults.less
- lib/
  - grid.less
  - mediaqueries.less
  (...) 
- template/
  - base.less
  - mobile.less
  - widemobile.less
  - tablet.less
  (...)
- main.less
```

The main.less file import the required libraries (e.g. mediaqueries.less). These provide mixing to use (e.g. .progressive-enhancement()). The mediaqueries library has multiple mixins that take care of template loading. See the docblock:

```
/**
 * Progressive enhancing overrides (mobile first)
 *
 * Mobile loads "mobile.less"
 * Wide mobile loads "mobile.less" and "widemobile.less"
 * Tablet loads "mobile.less", "widemobile.less" and "tablet.less"
 * etc.
 */
```

In addition, main.less also includes template/base.less for common styling ,font loading, custom mixins etc.

Since it was not possible for the mediaqueries library to handle the components in a nice way. This logic was moved to the them files. E.g. mobile.less:

```
(...)
/**
 * Imports
 */
@import (less) "../components/navbar/mobile.less";
@import (less) "../components/postslist/mobile.less";
@import (less) "../components/footer/mobile.less";
(...)
```

Whenever i need to overwrite a rule for a certain media query additional imports can be made to to other files (unfortunately no auto loading). E.g. tablet.less

```
(...)
/**
 * Imports
 */
@import (less) "../components/navbar/tablet.less";
@import (less) "../components/postslist/tablet.less";
```

Note that the footer is unchanged from mobile.

This solution might be a bit more verbose than the solution provided by @seven-phases-max but I think it's cleaner since variables don't need to be abused as parameters.

Comment: It's not that the verbosity is the main problem. If you try to re-use a this stuff in different projects for different set of components you have to explicitly create such import lists for every media yet again and again. And no, there's no variable abuse in either solution in any way. Variable are made to be also used in situations like above.